# FTP gateway file transfert with rest

Tags: java, rest, ftp, gateway

I am trying to create an **FTP Gateway** with **REST** and I have a question:

When I want to download a file on my computer via the gateway, do I have to :

- first download the file locally where the gateway is and then send it to the client ?

Or :

- can I send the file (to the client) while it is being downloaded from the **FTP** (because if the file is big it takes a loooot of time to be on the gateway, and then I have to wait for the file to be sent to me from the gateway)

I hope I am clear enough x)

Thanks for your help and suggestions :)

Comment: Try searching for a streaming FTP client library.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I know that the one I use (apache commons net) Take an OutputStream in parameter of the retrieveFile method, but I don't know if this can be used.